# Why am I using opengl glsl to implement skybox, getting something wrong?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm currently using glsl to draw a skybox, but final result of my program is not my expect, the six sides of the skybox looks like all sides flipped vertically, then flipped vertically. If I make the six image (right.bmp, left.bmp, top.bmp, and so on) vertical and vertical manually in some image editor, skybox works fine. To locate the problem within my program quickly, I simplify my program to draw only one side, front side.

My program screenshot:

image link: http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p668/nimaccc/front_zps741fc377.jpg

Original material:

image link: http://i1345.photobucket.com/albums/p668/nimaccc/original_zps3dbccf2e.jpg

Here is the relevant code :

**vertics shader:**

```
attribute  vec3 VertexPosition;
varying vec3 ReflectDir;

void main()
{
   ReflectDir = VertexPosition;

   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * vec4(VertexPosition,1.0);
}
```

**fragment shader:**

```
 varying vec3 ReflectDir;
 uniform samplerCube CubeMapTex; 

 void main() {
    vec4 cubeMapColor = texture(CubeMapTex,ReflectDir );

    gl_FragColor=  cubeMapColor;
 }
```

Some code within my opengl program:

This used for binding my cube map into shader.

```
 glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5);

    GLuint texID;
    glGenTextures(1, &texID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, texID);

    GLuint targets[] = {
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X,
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y,
        GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z
    };

    const char* baseFileName[] = {
    "Right",
    "Left",
    "Top",
    "Bottom",
    "Front",
    "Back"


    };

    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        string texName = string(baseFileName[i])+".bmp";

            IMAGE img;
            img.Load((char*)texName.c_str());
            img.ExpandPalette();

            glTexImage2D(targets[i], 0, GL_RGBA, img.width, img.height, 0,
                 img.format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, img.data);

    }

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    m_shader->compileandlink();
    m_shader->useprogram();
    m_shader->setUniform("CubeMapTex", 5);
    m_shader->unuseprogram();
```

And this 's my front side vertics, it's clock-wise winding.

```
    float extend2 = extend*.5f;
    m_cube_v = new vertex_t[24];

    //front
    m_cube_v[0].pos[0] = -extend2;
    m_cube_v[0].pos[1] = -extend2;
    m_cube_v[0].pos[2] = extend2;

    m_cube_v[1].pos[0] = extend2;
    m_cube_v[1].pos[1] = -extend2;
    m_cube_v[1].pos[2] = extend2;

    m_cube_v[2].pos[0] =  extend2;
    m_cube_v[2].pos[1] =  extend2;
    m_cube_v[2].pos[2] = extend2;

    m_cube_v[3].pos[0] = -extend2;
    m_cube_v[3].pos[1] = extend2;
    m_cube_v[3].pos[2] = extend2;
```

What went wrong?

Comment: It might be that you simply need to look into how you draw your cube indices.

Answer (score 2):

The origin of the OpenGL texture coordinate system is in the lower left corner of the image, that is why your skybox rendered upside down. You have to transform your texture, or mirror the texture coordinates to get the right result.

Comment: thank your replay, i dont' think that's correct answer.because not only skybox rended upside down, but also reversed from left to right.